# Laravel save with relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to save new user with relations?

User model:

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('Profile','id');
}
```

Profile model:

```
protected $table = 'users_personal';
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User','id');
}
```

Main function:

```
            $u                      = new User;
            $u->username            = $i['username'];
            $u->email               = $i['mail'];
            $u->password            = Hash::make( $i['password'] );
            $u->type                = 0;
            $u->profile->id         = $u->id;
            $u->profile->name       = $i['name'];
            $u->profile->surname    = $i['surname'];
            $u->profile->address    = $i['address'];
            $u->profile->number     = $i['strnum'];
            $u->profile->city       = $i['city'];
            $u->profile->ptt        = $i['ptt'];
            $u->profile->mobile     = $i['mobile'];
            $u->profile->birthday   = $i['year'].'-'.$i['mob'].'-'.$i['dob'];
            $u->profile->newsletter = $i['news'];
            $u->push();
```

If I do this I get an error: Indirect modification of overloaded property User::$profile has no effect

How can I save user profile when creating a new User?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create your `Profile` object and then attach it to your user.

```
$u                      = new User();
$u->username            = $i['username'];
$u->email               = $i['mail'];
$u->password            = Hash::make( $i['password'] );
$u->type                = 0;
$u->save();

$profile = new Profile();
$profile->id         = $u->id;
$profile->name       = $i['name'];
$profile->surname    = $i['surname'];
$profile->address    = $i['address'];
$profile->number     = $i['strnum'];
$profile->city       = $i['city'];
$profile->ptt        = $i['ptt'];
$profile->mobile     = $i['mobile'];
$profile->birthday   = $i['year'].'-'.$i['mob'].'-'.$i['dob'];
$profile->newsletter = $i['news'];

$u->profile()->save($profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$profile = new UserProfile( array( 
    'name' => $i['name'],
    'surname' => $i['surname'],
    // ...
) );

$user = new User( array(
    'username' => $i['username'],
    // ...
) );

$profile = $user->profile()->save($profile);
```

See the related [documentation entry](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models) for more information.